# How to select just the parent tag and change its attribute without affecting its children tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

In below HTML code I have inserted buttons under each `li` tags and I want to change the content inside the `li` tag as soon as I press it's corresponding button. But for this I am not able to select only the `li` tag (i.e. without its children button).

```html
<body>
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter" width='50px'>Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var ul= document.querySelector('ul')
var li=document.querySelectorAll('li');
li.forEach(function(i,value){ 
  var button=document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
  button.setAttribute('id',value)
  addButtonToTagList(i,button)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your addButtonToTagList function does, but it should call `appendChild` on the current `li`, passing it the button element you just created.

```js
var addButtonToTagList = function(item, value) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
  button.setAttribute('id', value);
  item.appendChild(button);
}
var ul = document.querySelector('ul')
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
li.forEach(function(item, value) {
  addButtonToTagList(item, value);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter" width='50px'>Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```